# Wordpress Plugin Authenticate With Facebook WIth No AppID

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I am working on my first wordpress plugin and posting to facebook. I have been looking for the last few days for ways to authenticate with facebook. I have found numerous sites that use the method of having the user create an App and then input the AppID and App Secret. However, I have used plugins before that use Oauth (I think) as it opens a pop up and the user basically logs into facebook and then says this app (your wordpress site) wants to control things.

Does anyone know of any resources for authenticating with Facebook without the user having to go through the trouble of creating apps?

Examples I have found but they require APPid and App Secrets.

http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/02/post-to-facebook-page-wall-using-php-graph http://www.pontikis.net/blog/auto_post_on_facebook_with_php

My anticipation is that they set up a website and create a single app for that.  Then the plugin calls that website, gets the access token, and sends it back?

The wordpress documentation is quite confusing to me.

Comment: You need to create an app, there's no other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an app takes about 5min, so I don't really see an obstacle here.

IMHO there's no other way than either

- Using an app with FB Login to obtain the permission to post on a user's/page's behalf, or,
- Getting an access token via the Graph Explorer and use this for your plugin

Please be aware that user access tokens expire after max. 60 days.

Comment: I was wanting to basically do what this plugin does.  https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-share-old-post-lite/

Comment: They're "assigning a profile", which means that they're probably using FB Login to get the appropriarte Access Tokens.